# Tricky grep command

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a text file containing lines of space separated data.

Example:

```
B  345678  2005-12-21  4174  1  62  11111 16543 1911  786543,45
```

However the spaces are kind of inconsistant and sometimes I suspect there are some added tabs too. 
I need to find a was to cut the line exactly before "62" which is a number that always occur in every line and it is somtimes followed by a 5-digit number and then always followed by another 5-digit number. I also add space before 62 to minimixe risk for mismatches.

So far I came up with this:

```
grep " 62 [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] " file
```

This will only give the lines where sometimes a 5-digit number shows up. I need a way to grep for 62 followed by an optional 5-digit numbers and then followed by a compulsary 5-digit number.

Can this be done?

/Paul

Comment: By "cut the line", you mean you want to remove the part before 62? You say "it's sometimes followed by a 5-digit number, and then always followed by another 5-digit number", but isn't that the same the other way around? We can't tell apart the 5-digit numbers without extra information on them.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove everything before 62 (or one space follewed by 62). The 5-digit numbers are always from 10000 and up to 99999. As I said 62 is followed by a space and a 5-digit number then space and another 5-digit number OR 62 is followed by a inconsistent number of spaces then comes the latter 5-digit number.

Comment: Is the  "62" always in the 6th column?

Comment: No, it is not. 62 could occur in any line as "62" or " 62" or " 62 ". That is why I need to make sure that the delimiter is the "true" 62 by knowing what comes after.

Comment: Please add a sample input file (showing different places "62" can appear, and matching/non-matching lines) as well as the corresponding output you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a way to grep for 62 followed by an optional 5-digit numbers and then followed by a compulsary 5-digit number.

That seems to be the same as saying that there's one or two 5-digit numbers after the `62`, and then it's enough to just match on the first one. Handling a varying amount of spaces is easy, we can use `␣+`, or `[[:space:]]+` to include tabs too.

So,

```
grep -E ' 62 +[1-9][0-9]{4} '
```

or

```
grep -E '[[:space:]]62[[:space:]]+[1-9][0-9]{4}[[:space:]]'
```

This of course will print the entire line. If you want just the part starting from 62, add `.*` to match the end of the line and `-o` to print just the matching part:

```
grep -o -E '[[:space:]]62[[:space:]]+[1-9][0-9]{4}[[:space:]].*'
```

Comment: ilkkachu. Your second grep command did the trick:-) The third one gives bland lines. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` for that purpose:

```
awk '{if (match($0, "(^[[:print:]]*[[:space:]]+)?(62([[:space:]]+[1-9][0-9]{4})?([[:space:]]+[[:print:]]*)?[[:space:]]+[1-9][0-9]{4}([[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]+[[:print:]]*)$)", a)!=0) print a[2];}' file.txt
```

This will match any line with an isolated `62`, either at the beginning or preceded by any number of printable characters and then one or more space characters, then followed by

- optionally whitespace and a five-digit number
- optionally any number of printable characters
- compulsory whitespace and a five-digit number
- optionally at least one whitespace and any number of printable characters, or whitespace to the end of line

It will print the part starting with the `62` to the end of line if such a pattern was found.

Note that this will not squash the separating whitespaces, so the "inconsistent spaces" will be copied to the output as-is.

Answer (score 0):

> ... remove everything before 62 (.....)

```
perl -pe 's/.*?(?= 62 +[1-9]\d{4} )//'
```

Where:

- `s/.*?...//`  - means remove everything = substitute by nothing
- `.*?(?= 62)`  - means something before 62...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
grep -E '\b62([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]{5}\b){1,2}'
```

where `\b` is a word boundary that will allow "62" at the start of the line or after a non-word character (like whitespace)